# CSS psudo class or psudo element selectors like after and before in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it feasible to use css **psudo class or psudo elements selectors** like **after, before,** etc in react native? Or any other way around out there?

I've referred the npm named [react-native-extended-stylesheet](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet) and also logged an [issue](https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet/issues/46) there. I am also aware that RN does not actually use/run the CSS, it is the JavaScript is what runs for styling.

Comment: before and after are the pseudo elements, part of HTML DOM. In react-native we never deal with HTML DOM, Its just a JavaScript running on the top of Android.

So I don't think you can use before and after in RN.

Comment: @manishkeer: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks :)